# Navbar dropdown is not showing in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here is [bootstrap navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

I just copied and pasted the same code to my angular project. However the dropdown is not showing correctly.

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-msq9rq)

I want two things to get help.

1. Showing the dropdown.
2. The original code used hardcode the dropdown items.

   ```
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
   </div>
   ```

Now I created an array in component ts file.

```
    this.items = [
      {name: 'Action', url: 'app/aaa'},
      {name: 'Another Action', url: 'app/bbb'},
      {name: 'Something else here', url: 'app/ccc'}
    ];
```

I want to use `*NgFor` to iterate the array instead of hard code. How to change the html?

Comment: You may have to make sure that you have made jQuery accessible to the angular application.

Comment: But I don't want to use jquery since it is an angular application. I want angular handle all. Is that possible?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples - all of the components have been written using angular methodology

Comment: agree with @Chris - Use the ng-bootstrap library. 10/10 recommend

Comment: Well, if there is an answer that fits my case that would be great. And ng-bootstrap is a little old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is mentioned in [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) you have to include few dependencies to make Bootstrap fully working.
To include libraries required by Bootstrap - you can add [script tags](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) to your `index.html` file. [At the end of `body`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-tvtxdz?file=src%2Findex.html).

```html
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Then, to iterate through `items` declared in component you can [use `*ngFor` like below](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-tvtxdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html):

```js
<a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" [href]="item.url">{{item.name}}</a>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-tvtxdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**If you don't want to use jQuery**: - you have to implement logic which will be responsible for action after toggle is clicked.

Here you can see [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-bootstrap-navbar-guyxca?file=src/app/app.component.html) which is implementing logic to toggle dropdown menu.

Comment: That is not an answer. If you think jQuery is required, can you please show how to add it in the demo? Also I have two questions. The second one has not been answered.

Comment: Although it works out, but if there is a way by using pure css that would be great.